# What is the name of the speaking style used when one wants to communicate a passage of music?

Tags: music

When someone wants to communicate a piece of music to someone else they will try to speak the music literally using nonsensical words. For example the start of Beethoven's Fifth Symphony could be communicated by saying:

> "duh duh duh duuuuuuh. duh duh duh duuuuuuh".

What is the name of this particular communication style? Is there even a name at all?

Comment: I can't find this on the internet, and I'm not sure how to spell it, but I've heard (and said) *ta ra ra* or perhaps *tarara*.  Except I think that involves producing the pitches.  I guess you're looking for something that only conveys the rhythm?

Comment: The style of speaking conveys rhythm and inflection. For example a guitar solo might be spoken by saying: "widdly widdly..." and heavy palm muted guitar would be "chug chug...". You would try to speak using the correct pitches, but it's not necessary. I swear I've heard the name of this before.

Comment: It's a form of [onomatopoeia](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/onomatopoeia). Also of interest, though perhaps not quite what you're looking for, are [systems of counting in music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_(music)).

Comment: I see this doesn't cut the mustard and if one of us wanted another to do whatever that's called, would we not say: 'Can you hum it?'

Answer (score 2):

**Tra-la-la** (n.)

> A set of nonsensical syllables used while humming a refrain
>
> Synonyms: tra-la
> [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/tra-la-la)

> A vocal utterance forming a musical phrase (usually ascending)
> expressive of gaiety or joy; also, a cadence or flourish on a horn or
> similar instrument.
>
> **1823** Lay on the dogs, in the name of the holy Saint Hubert!—Ha! ha! tra-la-la-lira-la!
> W. Scott, *Quentin Durward* vol. I. ix. 228
> [OED online]

---

> Some officers also seemed to have a wary sense that Lüttke was useful, because he was a sentimentalist. On the occasions when we had a radio to listen to, and they were
> broadcasting music for the troops, Lüttke would be singing and swaying
> a hand as if conducting a raucous beer hall. **When he didn't know the
> words, he'd just sing bum-bum-bum, tra-la-la-la-la.** These officers
> seemed to believe it was better for morale than nothing; it probably
> was.
> [Alexander Starritt; *We Germans*](https://books.google.com/books?id=kl3IDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT19&dq=didn%27t%20know%20%20the%20words%20tra-la-la&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLr8fjl5CEAxWHD1kFHSNlAlcQ6AF6BAgMEAI#v=onepage&q=didn%27t%20know%20%20the%20words%20tra-la-la&f=false) (2020)

> The Bard began to speak in a drowsy voice that made the boy feel warm
> and safe inside. The words didn't matter. The Bard could have been
> saying "**tra-la-la**" for all the difference it made but in fact he was
> actually making sense: ...
> [Nancy Farmer; *The Islands of the
> Blessed*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0wsHphJcjdYC&pg=PT34&dq=didn%27t%20know%20%20the%20words%20tra-la-la&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLr8fjl5CEAxWHD1kFHSNlAlcQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=didn%27t%20know%20%20the%20words%20tra-la-la&f=false) (2012)

> For the child who is learning English, a private way to practice the
> new language in a group sing-along is singing, "Sing along, sing
> along; and just sing **tra-la-la-la-la** [or substitute sounds] if you
> don't know this song ..."
> [Doris Pronin Fromberg *The All-Day
> Kindergarten and Pre-K Curriculum*](https://books.google.com/books?id=PRypAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT173&dq=sing%20tra-la-la%20if%20you%20don%27t%20know%20the%20words&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZnvbimZCEAxVBFVkFHZC3AHEQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=sing%20tra-la-la%20if%20you%20don%27t%20know%20the%20words&f=false) (2012)

It's also a verb:

> "Don't worry, you'll probably know some of the songs anyway, and if
> you don't, just **tra-la-la** along as best you can."
> "OK! I can
> **tra-la-la!**"
> [Jenny Pearson; *Operation Nativity*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Wix1EAAAQBAJ&pg=PT138&dq=%22just%20tra-la-la%22%20if%20you%20don%27t%20know%20the%20words&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIm7epm5CEAxXdEVkFHfaoAQAQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=%22just%20tra-la-la%22%20if%20you%20don%27t%20know%20the%20words&f=false) (2022)

> "It's no fit thing for a real man. A man should use his hands to make
> his living, not go **tra-la-la-ing** all over the place. ..."
> [Gilbert
> Morris and Lynn Morris; *The Alchemy*](https://books.google.com/books?id=PmmrGRf9WHQC&pg=PA15&dq=tra-la-la%20means%20to%20sing%20nonsense&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj6t-X9nJCEAxXNMVkFHejPC304ChDoAXoECAoQAg#v=onepage&q=tra-la-la%20means%20to%20sing%20nonsense&f=false) (2004)